# Is there a 720dp device with xxhdpi pixel density?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, genymotion, android-resolution

I am trying to design an android application that takes layout xmls from layout-sw720dp-port and has xxhdpi pixel density and I am using genymotion to create custom device emulators. But however I try, I cannot get a device resolution for the same. I have tried making devices with resolutions 1. 1920 x 1080, 480dp 2. 2560 x 1600, 480dp . But both these did not pick from layout-sw720dp-port. Can someone give me a device resolution that takes xml from layout-sw720dp-port and is xxhdpi.

Answer (score 1):

Both mentioned resolution are different in terms of android smallest width dir structure.After testing below mentioned cases in gennymotion.

1920 x 1080, 480dp  (assume for Nexus 5) layout dir should be 
layout-sw360dp-port

2560 x 1600, 480dp (assume for Nexus 10) layout dir should be 
layout-sw800dp-port

(port i hve added bcz you hve mentioned in question.may b u r handling orientation wise layout)

**

For particularly `layout-sw720dp` is for 10 inch tabs.
10 inch tab will take resource from that folder(layout-sw720dp)

And 7 inch tab will take resource from `layout-sw600dp`

---

For more details regarding multiscreen support pls check [this](http://goo.gl/HD55d2)

From eclipse layout design you can get more idea about dir structure.This dir which i hve mentioned i gt from eclipse.

Select device and from the available list[image]

Select Qualifiers for 1920 x 1080, 480dp(here i hve selected Nexus 5)
[image]

Select Qualifiers for 2560 x 1600(here i hve selected Nexus 10)
[image]

Comment: but what device(with what resolution) would take xml from layout-sw720dp-port ?

Comment: what are the other folders u hve added in your app to handle multiple screen support ?

Comment: layout-sw720dp-port, layout-sw720dp-port, layout, layout-large

Comment: and for which devices or resolutions you wants to target your app

Comment: all tablets, in portrait mode.

Comment: ok pls check updated answer.. i have marked ** where i hve update text

Comment: so you gt any other solution or suggestion to improvise thse things ... ? pls share it if u found anything .. thanks &  HTH :)